# Android RecyclerVew Adapter slow performance

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having performance issues with my recyclerview and I have read that the **onBindViewHolder** section of the **RecyclerView.Adapter** could be a cause for it. The main issue that I am having is just slow scrolling and sometimes it becomes unresponsive . This is my onBindViewHolder

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ArtistViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Artist artist = artists.get(position);

    holder.getBinding().artistImage.setImageBitmap(null);
    try {
        holder.setImage(artist, (int) DimensionUtil.convertDpToPixel(context, 120), (int) DimensionUtil.convertDpToPixel(context, 120));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (position == artists.size() - 1) {

        endOfListListener.EndOfListReached();
    }
    holder.getBinding().setArtistClickListener(listener);
    holder.getBinding().setArtist(artist);
    holder.getBinding().setPosition(position);
    holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();

}
```

is there anything in there that could be moved elsewhere to improve scrolling performance ? I do know that every item in onBindViewHolder is frequently accessed as your scrolling down the list .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are loading images (large images) on recyclerview. And onbindviewholder will attach images eveytime when u scroll the recyclerview.

Comment: Oh ok do you know of a better place to load those images than the OnBindViewHolder ?

Comment: To prevent onbindviewholder method to attach images again and again. Just set 1 property to recyclerview. myRecyclerView.setRecycleable(false);

Comment: And load thumbnail or small images on recyclerview. This will increase performance and loading speed.